# Log out from dropdown menu webbrowser in vb.net app

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

In my program a user can log in to a website in webbrowser1. but when I try to log out the logout button is buried beneath a drop down menu. The button has no ID or I would .Invokemember. I have tried clicking and opening the drop down with that method then tried to look for innertext and invoke but failed. can some help? here is the html stuff:

[HTML for the logout button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCFPe.png)

Most recent attempt was:

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
        If webpageelement.InnerText = "Logout" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Anybody please?

Comment: Found a work around